# gspread add rows at the top of google sheets

Tags: pandas, dataframe, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I am trying to insert a data frame into a Google table, but this replaces the existing data, therefore, I want to add empty rows first:

```
spread.df_to_sheet(df, index=False, sheet='test', start='A2', replace=False, headers=False)
```

I'm looking for something like, but for many rows in one request:

```
import gspread 
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
sheet = client.open('Workbook').worksheet('test')
_list = ['', '']
sheet.insert_row(_list, 2)
```

method `add_rows()` doesn't work, it's append rows into end

```
def add_rows(self, rows):
    self.resize(rows=self.row_count + rows)
```

I'm tried, but it works for a long time:

```
for i in range(60):
    sheet.insert_row('', 2)
```

Comment: How large is the data? It's not elegant, but you could read both dataframes, combine them, sort, then write over the original all within python.

Comment: Full data at google sheet about 26 thousand rows, but still I hope for a more practical option thanks for the help

Comment: You can see in the library source code that the [`insert_row()`](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/blob/e0af80a1b6ea2ad343af738f0a599fe64f63dd0d/gspread/models.py) method is designed to insert **one** single row. The method could be modified so that it can insert multiple of them. I suggest you create an issue in the library so this feature may be implemented. Cheers